# How to delete char in table attribute in QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, labeling

I need to label many items but in the table attribute field there are some char (#F) for every item that I have to delete.

The length of the description are not always the same.

I create a new field but I am not able to set the logic operation to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the field calculator to update the column removing unwanted chars:

```
replace( "mycolumn", '#F','')
```

You can also use this directly in an label expression, if you do not want to delete the char from the record. You have a long list of string function for you convenience.

[image]